# Problem with customized transposition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following headers:

```
cmpID, cmpNome, paID1, Qtd1, IsVenda1, paID2, Qtd2, IsVenda2, paID3, Qtd3, IsVenda3, paID4, Qtd4,   IsVenda4
```

And I would like to get a table (for a certain cmpID) with the design:

```
paID    Qtd  IsVenda
-------------------
paID1 Qtd1 IsVenda1
paID2 Qtd2 IsVenda2
...
```

Does anyone know a solution? Do I have to use UNION ALL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot using `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (paid1, qtd1, isvenda1),
             (paid2, qtd2, isvenda2),
             (paid3, qtd3, isvenda3)
     ) v(paid, qtd, isvenda);
```

You can add `where t.cmpid = @cmpid`.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `VALUES`. In Pseudo-SQL terms:

```
SELECT YT.cmpID,
       YT.cmpNome
       V.paID
       V.Qtd,
       V.IsVenda
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(YT.paID1,YT.Qtd1,IsVenda1),
                        (YT.paID2,YT.Qtd2,IsVenda2),
                        ...
                        (YT.paID9,YT.Qtd9,IsVenda9))V(paID, Qtd, IsVenda)
WHERE V.paID IS NOT NULL;
```